# How to prevent the Button to run the script if a specific cell in google sheet is empty (google sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have a script where data entered in sheet1 are saved automatically in sheet2 when a Button (save) is clicked.

However, even if the sheet1 is empty, users can click the Button whenever and it add unnecessary rows in sheet2 (with empty or incomplete information).

So I want the script / button not to work if the cells (ex. C8, C14, C32) are not field in.

I tried searching other related post but I found none for this specific example.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, `I have a script where data entered in sheet1 are saved automatically in sheet2 when a Button (save) is clicked. However, even if the sheet1 is empty, users can click the Button whenever and it add unnecessary rows in sheet2 (with empty or incomplete information). So I want the script / button not to work if the cells (ex. C8, C14, C32) are not field in.`. Can you add your current script in your question. And also, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Hi Tanaike. My goal is simple - disable the script from running (when they click the button) if the user doesn't fill any data in C8, C14, and C32.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion. I believe your goal will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition like

```
function myFunction () {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var condition = ss.getRange("C8").getValue()

 if(condition == ""){}
 else {
  put here the rest of your code
}
}
```

I'm assuming it's a kind of form. If you want to check column C, into its last row, change `"C8"` with `"C"+ss.getLastRow()`

If you need more cells to be checked, add more variables `condition2` `condition 3` and then check in the if statement: `if(condition =="" || conditions == "" || condition 3 = "")` and so on

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes, I want this in my Form. I will try what you suggested.